# Python cdecimal InvalidOperation

Tags: python, decimal, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to read financial data and store it. The place I get the financial data from stores the data with incredible precision, however I am only interested in 5 figures after the decimal point. Therefore, I have decided to use t = .quantize(cdecimal.Decimal('.00001'), rounding=cdecimal.ROUND_UP) on the Decimal I create, but I keep getting an InvalidOperation exception. Why is this?

```
>>> import cdecimal
>>> c = cdecimal.getcontext()
>>> c.prec = 5
>>> s = '45.2091000080109'
>>> # s = '0.257585003972054' works!
>>> t = cdecimal.Decimal(s).quantize(cdecimal.Decimal('.00001'), rounding=cdecimal.ROUND_UP)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  cdecimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'cdecimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

Why is there an invalid operation here? If I change the precision to 7 (or greater), it works. If I set s to be '0.257585003972054' instead of the original value, that also works! What is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

decimal version gives a better description of the error:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Feb 16 2012, 18:47:58) 
>>> import decimal
>>> s = '45.2091000080109'
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 5
>>> decimal.Decimal(s).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.00001'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 2464, in quantize
    'quantize result has too many digits for current context')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3866, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context
>>>
```

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

> Unlike other operations, if the length of the coefficient after the
> quantize operation would be greater than precision, then an
> InvalidOperation is signaled. This guarantees that, unless there is an
> error condition, the quantized exponent is always equal to that of the
> right-hand operand.

But i must confess i don't know what this means.

Comment: The problem is that the context "prec" does not mean what you and/or the OP think it means.  It's the total precision, not "precision after the decimal point".  1.2345 has five digits of precision, and so does 123.45, but 123.45000 has eight, not five, digits of precision.

Comment: thanks - that makes! is there a way to set a precision after the decimal point for a division operation i.e.?

Comment: There's only .quantize().  For doing scientific-notation-precision it's a pain but for your case it's easy, you just .quantize to .00001. :-)

Comment: Thanks! If I were a python dev, I would add question, answer and torek's comment to official docs :)